# How to retrieve JSON values to Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve the JSON data given below but I'm unable to.

Since I'm using Javascript Ajax success function, when I try doing alerts with the code,

```
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:myURL,
success : function(data) {
     alert(data);
     //{"object1":{"mainIsActive":"A","mainBuildingGL":"01493","mainIsUnderCons":"B"},"object2":[[{"statLabel":"Cafeteria","statCount":"1"},{"statLabel":"Restaurant","statCount":"2"}],[{"statLabel":"Cafeteria","statCount":"1"},{"statLabel":"Restaurant","statCount":"2"}],{"newBuildingGL":"15450"}]}
}
});
```

I am retrieving the below JSON data.

```
{"object1":{"mainIsActive":"A","mainBuildingGL":"01493","mainIsUnderCons":"B"},"object2":[[{"statLabel":"Cafeteria","statCount":"1"},{"statLabel":"Restaurant","statCount":"2"}],[{"statLabel":"Cafeteria","statCount":"1"},{"statLabel":"Restaurant","statCount":"2"}],{"newBuildingGL":"15450"}]}
```

But when I try trying to get the value of mainIsActive using:

```
alert(data.object1.mainIsActive);
```

I am getting the error in the console:

"Cannot read property 'mainIsActive' of undefined at Object.success (:143:30)"

Can you please help? I also attached the JSON image so you can understand the structure better.

[image]

Comment: please share the code

Comment: What is `typeof data`? You might have to parse the JSON first using `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: i don't think javascript make string conversion to JSON automatically, try doing `data = JSON.parse(data);` before

Comment: Hi @brk, shared the AJAX code I have. Basically I am getting the JSON data from a Java servlet. When I tried alerting the data, the result is shown above. I am trying to get the values from the whole json object but I am unable to.

Comment: @Ragome, try `alert(typeof(data))` and tell us what you've received.

Comment: Hi @str and @ekans, when I try doing `var json = JSON.parse(data);` and alerting the json variable, there is nothing coming out.

Comment: Hi @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut alert(typeof(data)) is "String"

Comment: @str **typeof data** is "String"

Comment: when you say nothing is really nothing or `[object Object]` ?

Comment: Hi @ekans sorry I am now getting the values with the use of JSON.parse(data). Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data will be available in object structure once you have parsed it using

```
JSON.parse(StringYouWantToParse)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work properly:

```
var x = '{"object1":{"mainIsActive":"A","mainBuildingGL":"01493","mainIsUnderCons":"B"},"object2":[[{"statLabel":"Cafeteria","statCount":"1"},{"statLabel":"Restaurant","statCount":"2"}],[{"statLabel":"Cafeteria","statCount":"1"},{"statLabel":"Restaurant","statCount":"2"}],{"newBuildingGL":"15450"}]}';
var data = JSON.parse(x); 
alert(data.object1.mainIsActive);
```